# How can i enable remote debugging iOS webapp?

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, safari, safari-web-inspector

I'm trying to use safari inspector for debugging web app on iOS device.

and I have referenced this way: [enable remote web-inspector](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)

It works when I try with iphone application developed by me (build & run by xcode to device).
but If I try to debug webapp installed using ipa, 
I can't find app in safari > Develop > iPhone menu. (this menu shows just 'No Inspectable Applications')

for example, in Android Webview, 
there is an api `SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`

If developer write `webview.SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)` everyone installed this app using apk can debug webview in Chrome.

is there any option like `SetWebContentsDebuggingEnabled` in iOS?

help-!

Answer (score 4):

Resolved!

you should check all below conditions.

1. Build for testing.
2. When you export your archive, choose "Save for Development Deployment." (available in XCode 7.0!)
3. you can 'remote debug' using only devices that you've registered to your apple developer account. So if you want to publish ipa to testers, you should get their test device's udid first.

   - can check application logs also in this way.

Answer (score 0):

lee!

Xcode 7.0 provides some build options.
Check the `Build Settings`.
You can select release or debug mode, maybe debug mode is able to connect to safari inspector.

For your web developer!

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on
H. Lee's Answer but want to confirm that this is still correct in 2023! Our testers were able to remote debug using their devices as long as the archive was distributed as "Development" method in organizer and their devices were registered in the Apple Developer portal, thanks!